# any way to prevent an echo printing out before its needed to do so?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

i have a multiplication table which works perfectly, save for one tiny mishap. i need the message "invalid entry!" to ONLY appear when i submit an empty query via my input field. the problem lies in the message being there, staring me in the face upon first opening the table form in my localhost.

any ideas? thanks in advance.

the code:

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="php32-table.php">
  <input type="text" name="num">
  <input type="submit" value="get table">
</form>

</html>

<?php

$num = isset($_POST["num"]) ? $_POST["num"] : "";
  if($num) {
  for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
  {
  $mul = $num * $i;
  echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
  }
  } else {
  echo "invalid entry!";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thats why you need function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the `$_POST["num"]` variable is set. This way you can know if the form has been posted.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["num"]))
  {
    $num = isset($_POST["num"]) ? $_POST["num"] : "";
    if ($num) {
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
      {
        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
      }
    } else {
      echo "invalid entry!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :) If this solved your problem, consider marking this as the solution to your problem so other users might also find this.

Answer (score 1):

Num will always be set since it is a textfield. What you need to do is check if the field is empty. The code below should work.

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if(!empty(trim($_POST['num'])) {
       $num = $_POST['num'];
       for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
       {
          $mul = $num * $i;  
          echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
       }
    } else {
         echo "invalid entry!";
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the link to action for testing purposes, I also prefer personally to run the PHP for the form within the same file, so my example below is exactly how to do that. You can always refer to your original and place the php within the `php32-table.php` file.

You can run this from the submission side by adding in `name="submit"` like below:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="num">
    <input type="submit" value="get table" name="submit">
</form>
```

You can then check if the submit button has been pressed by using `isset` and if it has been clicked then run the code between { } like below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $num = isset($_POST["num"]) ? $_POST["num"] : "";
    if ($num) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
        {
            $mul = $num * $i;
            echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "invalid entry!";
    }
}
?>
```

to be honest, to keep it cleaner i'd remove: `$num = isset($_POST["num"]) ? $_POST["num"] : "";` and simply change that line to:

```
if (!empty($_POST['num']))
{
    // run code 
} else {
    // output error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the $_POST['submit'] is set or not

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="php32-table.php">
  <input type="text" name="num">
  <input type="submit" name='submit' value="get table">
</form> 

</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

$num = isset($_POST["num"]) ? $_POST["num"] : "";


  if($num) {
  for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
  {
  $mul = $num * $i;
  echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
  }
  } else {
  echo "invalid entry!";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your input type to number.

```
<input type="number" name="num">
```

Here the PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST["num"])){

$num = $_POST["num"];


  if($num)
  {
      for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
      {
        $mul = $num * $i;
        echo "$num * $i = $mul<br>";
      }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "invalid entry!";
  }

}

?>
```